# soapUI error when testing for WSI compliance

Tags: java, eclipse, soapui

When I test my web service for WSI conformance I get a java exception thrown - please see console output below. I know the issue isn't caused by absence of a main() method as the service isn't an application.

soapUI Console output:

```
command: [cmd.exe, /C, C:\Web Services\eclipse\wsi-test-tools\java\bin\Analyzer.bat, -config, C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\wsi-analyzer-config6023712173002373188.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/xerces/dom/ElementImpl.setUserData(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/apache/xerces/dom3/UserDataHandler;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.wsi.xml.dom.DOMParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.wsi.xml.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.wsi.xml.XMLUtils.parseXML(Unknown Source)
    at org.wsi.xml.XMLUtils.parseXML(Unknown Source)
    at org.wsi.test.analyzer.config.impl.AnalyzerConfigReaderImpl.readAnalyzerConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.wsi.test.analyzer.config.impl.AnalyzerConfigReaderImpl.readAnalyzerConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.wsi.test.analyzer.config.impl.AnalyzerConfigImpl.parseArgs(Unknown Source)
    at org.wsi.test.analyzer.Analyzer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.wsi.test.analyzer.BasicProfileAnalyzer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.wsi.test.analyzer.BasicProfileAnalyzer.main(Unknown Source)
```

Log Output:

```
ERROR:An error occurred [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.], see error log for details
```

When I run `C:\Web Services\eclipse\wsi-test-tools\java\bin\Analyzer.bat, -config, C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\wsi-analyzer-config6023712173002373188.xml]` directly from command prompt I get:

```
Analyzer Error: The specified option is not supported: ,.
```

For some reason soapUI doesn't run the service but analyses the generated WSDL. WSI compliance html report file is generated but with no content. I suspect this might be a result of a configuration issue. I've double checked the following:

- Java applets run correctly in Eclipse
- Logs directory has been created
- soapUI preference is correctly entered
- WSI_HOME environment variable is correctly set up

Any ideas what might be causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have incompatible jars:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/xerces/dom/ElementImpl.setUserData(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/apache/xerces/dom3/UserDataHandler;)Ljava/lang/Object
```

But without seeing your dependencies i can not say which.

Comment: I've created a project in soapUI from WSDL. The service runs as expected. Only the WSI conformance report isn't generated properly